# Stripe not charging the card

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm having an issue with Stripe where it will happily create the token and send that over to my php charging script, at which point a `200 OK - Token` log is created on the Stripe control panel. It just will not charge the card, as far as I can see I've done everything properly, I'm getting no errors, in php or from the Stripe API.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$error = 0;

require_once('stripe-php-master/init.php');

$trialAPIKey = "sk_test_???";  // These are the SECRET keys!
$liveAPIKey = "sk_live_???";

\Stripe\Stripe::$apiBase = "https://api-tls12.stripe.com";

// Switch to change between live and test environments

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($trialAPIKey);
/* \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($liveAPIKey); */

$token = $_POST['token'];
$price = $_POST['amount'];
$price = $price * 100;
$desc = $_POST['desc'];

try {
  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $price,
    "currency" => "gbp",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => $desc
    ));
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined
  $error++;
}

if($error>=1) {
    echo "There was an error processing your card, please try again.";
} else {
    echo "Thank you, your payment was successful.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code to stripe sucessfull charge.

```
<?php
require_once("stripe2/init.php");
$card_no = '4242 4242 4242 4242';
$card_exp = '05 / 20';
$card_cvc = '123';
$token  = createstripetoken($card_cvc,$card_exp,$card_no);
$testcharge = charges(10,$token); 
echo $testcharge;

function charges($amount,$token)
{
 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
 "amount" => $amount * 100,
 "currency" => "usd",
 "source" => $token, 

 ));
$succes = 'your one time charges successfully';
return $succes;
 }
function createstripetoken($card_cvc,$card_exp,$card_no)

{

  $exp_month = substr($card_exp,0,2);

  $exp_year = substr($card_exp,5,2);


  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("your key here");



   $data = \Stripe\Token::create(array(

     "card" => array(

     "number" => $card_no,

     "exp_month" => $exp_month,

    "exp_year" => $exp_year,

    "cvc" => $card_cvc

     )

    ));

  $response = json_decode(json_encode($data), True);

 $token = $response['id'];
 return $token;
  }
  ?>
```